# Shopify: Buy Button not adding to bag

Tags: shopify, liquid

I added an if statement to my product page to make it so that if there's only 1 variant for a product - usually the 'Default Title' variant - Don't display any and just hide it. But for some reason this has broke my add to cart button? Not too sure why?

```
      <form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      {% if product.options.size > 1 %}
        <fieldset class="group">
          <ul class="checkbox">
            {% for variant in product.variants %}
            {% if variant.available == true && %}

                  <li>
                    <label>
                    <input type="radio" value="{{variant.id}}" name="id" />
                    {{ variant.title }} for {{ product.price | minus:variant.price | money_with_currency }}
                    </label>
                  </li>
            {% else %}
            {% endif %}
            {% endfor %}
          </ul>
        </fieldset>
        {% endif %}
            <input type="submit" name="add" id="add" class="inpost-buy w-button" value="Add to Bag →"></input>
      </form>
```

Comment: Your if statement is not complete `{% if variant.available == true && %}` why is there `&&` when there is no additional condition to check?

Comment: Removing this still causes the error 'Parameter Missing or Invalid: Required parameter missing or invalid: id'

Answer (score 0):

An hidden field with variant.id parameter as value is missing in your else statement.